# Can pipenv sync --dev only install the package version specified in [dev-packages]?

Tags: python, synchronization, pipenv

I have the numpy package specified in my Pipfile as follows:

```
[packages]
numpy = "==1.19.5"

[dev-packages]
numpy = "*"
```

I'd like `pipenv sync --dev` to only install the package version listed in **[dev-packages]** when using the *--dev* flag when the same package is present in both [packages] and [dev-packages]. This doesn't seem to be the behavior of the --dev flag, it seems to try and install both packages. Is there a simple way to achieve this?